# Matrix python coding using def

Tags: python

Question:

Write a function that displays an n-by-n matrix using the following header:

```
def printMatrix(n):
```

Each element is `0` or `1`, which is generated randomly.

Write a test program that  prompts the user to enter `n` and displays an n-by-n matrix. Here is a sample run:

```
n = 3
 010
 000
 111
```

I don't understand or even start the code. Can someone help me?

This is what I have so far:

```
from random import randint

def printMatrix(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            print(randint(0, 1), end="")
        print("")
number = input("Choose your number: ")
printMatrix(int(number))
```

Comment: Can you generate a random number?

Comment: Use a nested `for` loop.

Comment: yes i can generate a random number

Comment: Then show us how. To help you, we have to know where you're stuck.

Comment: a clue `random.randint(0,1)`, now how would you do that `n` times?

Comment: Is it getting better

Comment: Can some one help me on my other Question please?

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

def printMatrix(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            print(randint(0, 1), end="")
        print("")
number = input("Choose your number: ")
printMatrix(int(number))
```

Comment: Hello. Please refrain from posting code-only answers. Instead, explain what is happening beforehand, afterward, or in comments.